# I working through little lisper. The function lat? checks whether all elements of list are atoms or not

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun lat
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null l) t)
          ((atom (car l))(lat (cdr l))
          (t nil))))
```

The function takes a list as an argument. It is a recursive function that checks every element in the list. Whether it is atom or not. If every element is an atom, then it returns true else false.

Following is the error displayed
While compiling LAT :

```
Bad lambda list : (LAMBDA (L)
                    (COND ((NULL L) T) ((ATOM # #)) (T NIL)))
   [Condition of type CCL::COMPILE-TIME-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

Comment: DEFUN requires a function name first. That's LAT. What should the next element after the function name be in a DEFUN? Check the syntax for DEFUN and then look at your code. What is different?

Comment: (defun <function-name> (<args>) <body>) . In my code snippet I have named the function lat, and passed the lambda function as an argument to lat. lambda function has an parameter l which takes a list as an argument.

Comment: so it expects (<args>) and you haven't provided that. You have provided something else, which is not supported. What would you need to change?

Comment: `defun` already implies that a function follows so `lambda` is redundant.

Comment: (defun lat (l) (cond ((null l) t)
          ((atom (car l))(lat (cdr l))
          (t nil))))  should be the code. I didn't knew lambda is redundant in clisp. Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

Just like Hal Abelson called Scheme "lisp" in the SICP videos this book does the same, however the language in the book is a predecessor to Scheme and not Common Lisp. When you see:

```
(define name 
  (lambda (arg ...) 
    body ...)
```

This is the same as this in CL:

```
(defun name (arg ...)
  body ...)
```

The reason is that in Scheme it's the same namespace for operator as well as operand bindings. A lisp-2 like Common Lisp can split it up like this:

```
(setf (fdefinition 'name)
  (lambda (arg ...)
    body ...))
```

This probably won't happen since you can always use `defun`, but in the event you return a function from a function you can do this or you must rely on `funcall` or `apply` to use the returned value:

```
;; This is a function that creates a function
(defun get-counter (from step)
  (lambda ()
    (let ((tmp from))
      (incf from step)
      tmp)))
```

When using this you might want to bind it globally:

```
(setf (fdefinition 'evens) (get-counter 0 2))
(evens) ; ==> 0
(evens) ; ==> 2
```

Or in functions you get it bound to normal variables and need to `funcall` or `apply`:

```
(defparameter *odds* (get-counter 1 2))
(funcall *odds*)
; ==> 1
```

Which one do you prefer?

```
(list (funcall *odds*) (evens))
; ==> (3 4)
```

The ? in `lat?` inidicated predicate and in CL a p in the end does the same. Your function `latp` is suppose to return `nil` or `t` so it should not return a function at all. Thus:

```
(defun latp (list)
  (cond ((null list) t)
        ((atom (car list)) (latp (cdr list)))
        (t nil)))
```

This of course is the same as:

```
(defun latp (list)
  (or (null list)
      (and (atom (car list))
           (latp (cdr list)))))
```

Unlike Scheme using the name `list` as the argument does not affect the function call to `list`.

Comment: It is `defun` instead of `defin` in our last function definition, isn‘t it?

Comment: Thanks @Martin. My brain probably fought between `define` and `defun` and I got something in between like in Hofstadter' s talk about analogies. May Yuletide joys be ever thine